# Change search field's icon

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsimage, nssearchfield

I try to implement search behavior like in Xcode: if you enter something in search field, icon changes color.

I delegate both *searchFieldDidStartSearching* and *searchFieldDidEndSearching* to controller and change the image.
The problem is icon's image changes only when window lose it's focus.

[image]

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchField: NSSearchField!

    func searchFieldDidStartSearching(_ sender: NSSearchField) {
        print("\(#function)")

        (searchField.cell as! NSSearchFieldCell).searchButtonCell?.image = NSImage.init(named: "NSActionTemplate")
    }

    func searchFieldDidEndSearching(_ sender: NSSearchField) {
        print("\(#function)")

        (searchField.cell as! NSSearchFieldCell).searchButtonCell?.image = NSImage.init(named: "NSHomeTemplate")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas/suggestions.

Comment: I made some modifications to your project, can you contact me on skype i have some images. (rawandahmad10@outlook.com) i'm sure i'll be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve problem by subclassing *NSSearchFieldCell* and assign this class to field's cell.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. A simple override fixed this issue for me

```
extension NSSearchField{
    open override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I don't know the reason, it works:

```
NSApp.mainWindow?.resignMain()
NSApp.mainWindow?.becomeMain()
```

Here is the whole code:

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController {
    private lazy var searchField: NSSearchField = {
        let searchField = NSSearchField(string: "")

        if let searchButtonCell = searchField.searchButtonCell {
            searchButtonCell.setButtonType(.toggle)
            let filterImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "filter")
            searchButtonCell.image = filterImage.tinted(with: .systemGray)
            searchButtonCell.alternateImage = filterImage.tinted(with: .systemBlue)
        }
        searchField.focusRingType = .none
        searchField.bezelStyle = .roundedBezel
        searchField.delegate = self

        return searchField
    }()

    ...
}

extension MyViewController: NSSearchFieldDelegate {
    func searchFieldDidStartSearching(_ sender: NSSearchField) {
        sender.searchable = true
    }

    func searchFieldDidEndSearching(_ sender: NSSearchField) {
        sender.searchable = false
    }
}

extension NSSearchField {
    var searchButtonCell: NSButtonCell? {
        (self.cell as? NSSearchFieldCell)?.searchButtonCell
    }

    var searchable: Bool {
        get {
            self.searchButtonCell?.state == .on
        }

        set {
            self.searchButtonCell?.state = newValue ? .on : .off
            self.refreshSearchIcon()
        }
    }

    private func refreshSearchIcon() {
        NSApp.mainWindow?.resignMain()
        NSApp.mainWindow?.becomeMain()
    }
}

extension NSImage {
    func tinted(with color: NSColor) -> NSImage? {
        guard let image = self.copy() as? NSImage else { return nil }
        image.lockFocus()
        color.set()
        NSRect(origin: NSZeroPoint, size: self.size).fill(using: .sourceAtop)
        image.unlockFocus()
        image.isTemplate = false
        return image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see when you click inside the view it's still focussed on the search text field(as you can still type in it after you clicked underneath it). Since the change image is on when it loses focus, you should check if you clicked outside of the text field.

Comment: As I mentioned in question icon changes only if window lose focus, not the field itself.

Comment: Yes and as I mentioned you should check when you click inside the application but outside the text field.

Comment: Nope, even if I move focus to another field icon does not changed until the whole window loses it focus.
Anyway I already figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to subclass `NSSearchFieldCell`.
When you create your `NSSearchField` from code, you can do something like this:

```
if let searchFieldCell = searchField.cell as? NSSearchFieldCell {
    let image = NSImage(named: "YourImageName")
    searchFieldCell.searchButtonCell?.image = image
    searchFieldCell.searchButtonCell?.alternateImage = image // Optionally
}
```

If you're using storyboards, you can do the same in `didSet` of your `@IBOutlet`.